# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\vue-tailwind-naive\tailwind.config.js'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tailwind-css

So I have been trying to install tailwind inside a Vue Project.

I initialized the vue project using:
`vue create project-name`.

Then I add tailwind as a plugin using the command:
`vue add tailwind` and then select the **minimal** option. I suspect the plugin is installed correctly but still I get the below error :

[image: Error]

In the package.json, tailwind & autoprefixer can be seen correctly installed. Also `postcss.config.js` & `vue.config.js` files have been added successfully & correctly.

[image: Screen]

But when I run to serve the page, I get this error:
[image]

I can't figure out what's going wrong here. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to delete the `postcss.config.js` then run the following command at the project root :

```
 npx tailwindcss init -p
```

this command will create `postcss.config.js` and `tailwind.config.js` files.

Comment: Hey this worked. Can you tell me the reason behind why what was happening was happening?

Comment: You was missing the `tailwind.config.js` file

Comment: But shouldn't ```vue add tailwind``` add it by default?
Anyways thank you :-)

Comment: You're welcome, I think that's an issue in vue cli which I've not used it since a while, I prefer vite

Comment: Anybody having same issue, after entering the command:
```npx tailwindcss init -p``` , 
it creates a tailwind.config.js which is basically empty, .i.e. none of the fields will have any value.

You will have to add the following to the **content** field for tailwind to correctly apply to pages with those extensions:

```purge: { content: ['./public/**/*.html', './src/**/*.vue'] },```

Without the above in vue, tailwind will not correctly apply.
Purge is deprecated, if you encounter any issues eliminate purge & its curly brackets just keeping content & its properties.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I changed the `("./tailwind.config.js")` to `("./tailwind.config.cjs")` in postcss.config.cjs plugins

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Using typescript, the problem is solved changing the settings.json from vscode.

To access the file settings, use the Command Palette Cmd + Shift + P for macOS or Ctrl + Shift + P for Windows and then type “Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)”

Find for  `"tailwindCSS.experimental.configFile":` parameter and then change it from  `"tailwind.config.js"` to `"tailwind.config.ts"`

The final parameter will be like this:
`"tailwindCSS.experimental.configFile":"tailwind.config.ts"`

If you are running `npm run dev`, stop and run again

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).